# Conjunctive Normal Form evaluates true when atleast half of the clauses are true.

Tags: satisfiability, conjunctive-normal-form

This is an Exam question.

Which of the Following is TRUE about formulae in Conjunctive Normal form?

-For any formula, there is a truth assignment for which at least half the clauses evaluate true.

-For any formula, there is a truth assignment for a which all the clauses evaluate to true.

-There is a formula such that for each truth assignment at most one fourth of the clauses evaluate to true.

-None

The answer given is :
"For any formula, there is a truth assignment for which at least half the clauses evaluate true."

To which I doubt too much!

This problem is asked earlier on this site itself but the accepted answer is somehow not at all satisfying to me.(may be I am a dumba**)

So here is what I interpreted step by step:

1. Interpretation of CNF form:
   E=(a+b+c)(a+b'+c)(a+b'+c')

(E is the expression/formula)
In short product of sum's of literals.

2. Interpretation of term 'clauses':
   Here in the above case there are 3 clauses. And In the total expression I am having 3 literals a, b, c.
3. Interpretation of the problem :
   Now First choice says:
   "For any formula, there is a truth assignment for which at least half the clauses evaluate true."

Means (what i understood):
We are simply asked to find for E = 1 how many clauses should evaluate to true?
(As soon as I saw this question.. my first answer that popped In my head is: 100%..to which I agree still now)
Why / How 100%  ?
My answer would be : "how on Earth would some one multiply 0's and get 1?!".
What I feel those all clauses must evalute to true!!

***Analogy***:

π = X * Y *Z
(π is simply notation where the product is stored..!)
This is a product of 3 bits.
With 3 bits I can have 8 possibles combinations for these..
000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111
Now only 111 is the case when π would be 1(which is very obvious..even for a school kid )

Why? Bcoz x=y=z=1 so π=1 * 1 * 1 = 1

And in all 7 other options cases the product would be obviously zero.

That means for product of 3 term to be 'not zero' all three have to be 1 only!!
(Yes ofcourse right..or am i wrong here too!!?)

This is the basis for my ans being 100%

So, I think all the clauses must evalute to true, unless that happens, E can't be 1, it would be 0 only..(?)

Plz explain the option, and also comment on my interpretation ..whether that is correct in any sort?

Any help would be much regarded!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As regards your attempt to interpret the problem, for your example
$$E=(a+b+c)(a+b'+c)(a+b'+c')$$
there are $3$ clauses, namely
$$a+b+c,\;\;a+b'+c,\;\;a+b'+c'$$
But the claim is not about assignments that make $E$ true.

Rather, the claim is that there is some assignment of truth values to the variables that makes at least half of the $3$ clauses true.

For this particular example, using $a=1$ and any truth values for $b,c$ makes all $3$ clauses true.

If instead we take the example
$$E=(a)(a')(a')$$
the truth value $a=0$ makes $2$ of the $3$ clauses true, but no truth value for $a$ makes all $3$ clauses true.

Let's consider the actual claim . . .

**Claim:**

If $P$ is a $\text{CNF}$ expression of the form $P=P_1\land \cdots \land P_k$ with variables in $\{X_1,...,X_n\}$, there is some truth assignment to the variables $X_1,...,X_n$ such that at least half of $P_1,...,P_k$ evaluate to true.

**Proof:**

Choose any truth assignment for the variables.

If at least half of $P_1,...,P_k$ evaluate to true, we're done.

If not, more than half of $P_1,...,P_k$ must evaluate to false, hence by negating the chosen truth value assignments for the variables, those of $P_1,...,P_k$ which evaluated to false will evaluate to true, so again we're done.

Comment: Your proof is excellent got my concepts cleared..@quasi Thank You!

Comment: bcoz this was an exam question..so I found many proofs for this question..they were using Binomial distribution. So my question is ...is it right to use Binomial distribution here..? Coz those solutions consider N clauses as N independent trials...and each clause may evaluate as True/False so satisfied the conditions, and then they claim No. Of success's = $n*p=n*1/2$ Buy how legitimate is that to consider these as n independent trials..coz I don't see whether any clause is independent ..coz we had already fixed the value of literals so they are dependent isn't it?

Comment: Do you have a link or reference to any of these other solutions?

Comment: Link 1: https://www-geeksforgeeks-org.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/gate-gate-cs-2007-question-48/amp/?amp_js_v=a2&amp_gsa=1&usqp=mq331AQFKAGwASA%3D#aoh=15934298207805&csi=1&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.geeksforgeeks.org%2Fgate-gate-cs-2007-question-48%2F

Comment: And the $n*1/2$ logic was told by my teacher to me..

Comment: Yes even I wasn't getting convince with that kind of logic..! And what about that $n*1/2$ claim ? Like can we actually apply binomial distribution here...and use it's expectation formula=$np=n*1/2$

Comment: Okay finally got the concept clear..! Thanks again for the excellent proof!

Comment: @Piyush Sawarkar: Ok, the argument in that link needs to be cleaned up, but that approach actually _does_ work. In any case, my argument is much simpler.

Comment: Hmm..yeah but that independence part still doesn't give a good feel in the answer given in that link..

Comment: Expectation of a sum is the sum of the exptectations, even without independence.

Comment: Oh yes! In that sense It does work...you are right...but still I liked your approach its simply much more satisfying..!